# JLabel's Set Location inside for not moving smoothly

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jlabel

i'm using a label for a little sprite for some testing that i'm doing, but i want to move the sprite 10 pixels per keypress. Now, i can do that, but now i'm trying to make it move the 10 pixels smoothly, so i tried the next code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        x++;
        container.setLocation(x, y);
        System.out.println(x);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is that, the sprite only moves when the for cycle ends, but the console shows the X value changing for each iteration. Any thoughts/help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look at how to animate a JComponent using [Swing Timer class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), instead of for loop. You can find various tutorials about [how to use Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). Here, to briefly explain, you are blocking [EDT(Event Dispatch Thread)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) which operates the graphical side of the Java. Whenever you want to make a constant and smooth flow in your animations, make sure that *you never block the EDT*.

**EDIT:** Here is the demonstration of the usage of Swing Timer Class:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class AnimationTrial extends JFrame {

    private final int DELAY = 10;

    private Timer timer;
    private int x, y;
    private JLabel label;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable () {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new AnimationTrial();
            }

        });
    }

    public AnimationTrial()
    {
        setSize(500, 500);
        x = 50;
        y = 50;

        label = new JLabel("They see me movin' they hatin'!");

        timer = new Timer( DELAY, new ActionListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                x++;
                label.setLocation(x, y);    
            }

        });
        timer.start();

        getContentPane().add(label);
        pack();
        setVisible (true);
    }

}
```

Comment: This. If you don't want to add another framework, this is the way to go. I think the italics are not enough, this needs to be in bold 72 font. :)

Comment: Thanks! I knew i was blocking something in the UI, but i didn't what what was it. I've found on the internet about the Timer Class, but as i said, is that i don't want the user to be able to press another key while the sprite is moving. I know i can even do it with this, but it involves more code, that's why i used the for loop, but apparently it's not gonna work. I'm gonna try this and come back to tell you the results.

Comment: And how do i stop it after the 10 pixels have passed? I want to move the sprite 10 pixels after the T key is pressed.

Comment: You can declare an integer variable after the amount or times you want to iterate the timer, then call the method timer.stop(); and you are done.

Comment: OHH NICE! I made it. Thank you dude!

Answer (score 2):

If you dont create new Thread, the user interface runs on the same thread as its method.

Therefore your for-cycle is fired after some action and thread cant do anything else until it ends.

Solution : Create your own class, pass the JLabel or the whole form as parameter in constructor, implement threading and run it as new thread.

Comment: The code the i show in this post it's inside my own class, it's name Sprite, it has a JLabel inside, and this code runs in a method that i created called forTest, it runs when i press the T key in the window, so the main window has a keylistener, i press the T key, and this happens. My code it's not optimized by any means but i'm just doing some testing for the final implementation.

Any example of how can i do what you mean?

Comment: Also, i don't want that the user can create a new input while the for is still running, that's why i didn't use a timer and used a for instead. But apparently it backfired haha.

Comment: KeyListener is not fired (automatically) in different thread, it just "listen" :). And yes, you can use timer as well. However you have to manually care about what user can and cannot do in middle of some action.

Comment: @HectorHammett However, when KeyListener is called, it will be in the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), the same one in charge of repainting and handling user input. If you make it sleep then, you freeze the application.

Comment: I have to clarify something, i said that my class it's called sprite because it's easier to undestand, but because i speak spanish, it's not actually called sprite, it's called "Monito". I'm telling you this, because, my class "Monito" already extends to a class called "Sprite", monito being the user, and sprite it's gonna be used to every other enemy or anything else.
Sprite -> Monito.
So, again, could you give me an example? Or i am complicating everything? haha.

Comment: It doesnt matter how "deep" your class is. If you dont create new thread, it is all fired in the same thread -> if you block thread, you block everything, even the redrawing of your application, therefore you cant see the movement.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you give a look to the [Timing Framework](https://java.net/projects/timingframework/pages/Home), if you want to do something close to an animation in Swing. It could help you, depending on your general need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want other sprites to move in sync with your sprite you can create a `TimerTask` and use [scheduleAtFixedRate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29). Your `TimerTask` would then be responsible for moving all sprites and redrawing everything that was part of the moving like the `JPanel` in the background and the sprites.

To make your code snippet work you would have to add redrawing of the Background and the sprite after setting the location but I would advise against that approach as it can easily lead to badly designed code where you create one God Class that does everything.

The `TimerTask` approach should also be more precise if the calculations need a bit time as it tries to have the same time between 2 calls where the approach with the sleeping thread can easily lead to different delays if the calculations are finished earlier or later.